# Waveforms on the raspberry pi using C#

Tags: timing, waveform, raspberry-pi-zero

I am about to start work on a raspberry pi project, and I am planning on building my application using Mono and C#.

I see the library called "RaspberryIO" which can be found [here](https://github.com/unosquare/raspberryio). This seems to have the basic GPIO functions, and has (the option of) pigpio as the control library.

My project requires fast pulsing of the control wires on a stepper driver, but I already know of the difficulty of getting decent sub-millisecond timing with an underlying operating system.

The solution to this problem is of course [wave chains](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=234559), which use the [hardware on the board](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/76989/how-does-pigpios-wave-chain-method-happen-in-hardware) to pull off a trick that produces accurate timing. Unfortunately, I am not seeing any extension in RaspberryIO for it.

I want to know if there is a library that supports wave chaining outright, OR if there is a way to pull this off by calling a command line utility or some other solution (I am not sure what DMA really entails in this case. I am not familiar with it at all.) that can be used from Mono or a .NET application in order to get short, pulsed output like this.

Comment: You can check: Windows.Devices.Gpio. Or you can access directly from c code, by call mmap() at first.

Comment: Windows.Devices.Gpio is likely not to be an option, as I don't think Mono supports it, and it seems that it doesn't support anything past PWM (which my library already supports) anyway.
I am fairly certain pigpio does a "hacky" thing to make wave chains work. I think I'll write a small python script then just shell.run it in order to achieve my goals.

Comment: If you think that is no available for mono, you can use Windows 10 IoT: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-windows-10-iot-raspberry-pi-3 and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/getting-started-with-windows-10-iot-core-raspberry-pi-3b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the Unosquare folks already had a library [here](https://github.com/unosquare/pigpio-dotnet), known as pigpio-dotnet, for directly using pigpio. This provides access to the functions I need, but wont be abstracted and have as pretty code as RaspberryIO would have.